# How to get rid of undefined error when closing a dialog box?

Tags: angular, angular-material

There are two components that transmit data between each other. If  just close the child dialog box without selecting data, then this error occurs:

> Cannot read property 'contractor_id' of undefined

parent component:

```
...
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(
  contractors => {
    this.form.get('SPR_CONTRACTORS_ID').patchValue(contractors.contractor_id)
    this.form.get('CONTRACTOR_NAME').patchValue(contractors.contractor_name)
  }
);
...
```

child component close:

```
  close() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
```

How to fix this error if I just close the window without selecting data?

Comment: Your post is missing some code part where you have contractors defined. The error is saying it's not defined, so look up there

Comment: Please read how important is to provide [mcve]

Comment: Just add an if ?

Comment: @David I just want to close the dialog box, and to add nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you close your dialog, you don't pass anything to the `close` function, therefore the `contractors` value will be `undefined` in your `dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe` block.

You can add a simple `if`-statement to prevent this error. If you now close your dialog and pass nothing, the form will not be updated as `contractors` is `undefined`.

```
 dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(
  contractors => {
    if (contractors) {
      this.form.get('SPR_CONTRACTORS_ID').patchValue(contractors.contractor_id)
      this.form.get('CONTRACTOR_NAME').patchValue(contractors.contractor_name)      
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see: you get your `contractors` from the `afterClose` subscription but your `close` is returning nothing:

```js
  close() {
    this.dialogRef.close(this.contractors);
  }
```

may be your solution (assuming `contractors` is defined in this component)